# nginx & php-fpm & clean urls

Tags: nginx, web-server, php-fpm, chroot

Hello i would like set up nginx like I want. I have read a lot of manuals (including official) but i can't make it work as I expect.

I have next urls: /user/register, /user/login, /user/logout etc ...  no any urls with php files.

So i would like to pass all non real file urls to fast-cgi server. Btw, fpm working in chroot.

This is my config file:

```
 server {

    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4

    server_name  domain;
    root   /var/www/domain/htdocs; 
    include /etc/nginx/security;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 6000;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ @php-fpm;
    }


    location @php-fpm {
       fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;

       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /htdocs;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

in nginx log i see:

```
 - - [31/May/2012:16:02:12 +0300] "GET /user/register HTTP/1.1" 403 46 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5"
```

in fpm log the next:

```
- -  31/May/2012:13:02:12 +0000GET /user/register403 /var/www/domain/htdocs/user/register 0.215 512 0.00%
```

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and nginx 1.1.19

P.S. On screen (in browser) i see only that text "No input file specified."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

So, you see in logs exactly what you have configured. Probably, you want something like:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/your/script.php;
```

Comment: you are absolutely right, thank you very much, and I solved that problem i got notification about you answer. In any case thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You've misconfigured `try_files`. As you can see in your php-fpm log, the exact url is being passed to the PHP server, which then attempts to get a file with that name, which of course doesn't exist.

What you need to do is either a rewrite or just change the passed file and then handle the given url within that script.

Adapted from my own nginx config:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;


location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

This configuration will forward all .php files to php_fpm. If you'd rather that .php files are not accessible at all directly, you'll need to use [internal](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#internal), which would hide them from the outside world, though in most cases you don't need to.

Using this configuration, all requests will be forwarded to `index.php`. To extract data about the page the user wants to view, look into PHP's `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. If you'll be exploding that string by `/`, keep in mind that the first array entry will be empty.

Comment: Actually my final config looks like this http://o7.no/K1Vq9a. My task is ro prevent even direct access to absolutely any php files, only clean urls, and all of them  should be redirected to one file index.php (in my example i did not prevent access to php files yet)